# "Approve" or "Reject" copy/paste documentation proposals

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-proposals

Should I "Approve" or "Reject" a contributation that copy/paste the documentation as it is from another website? is there any documentation section when I could find "approve/reject" reasons?

**Example :**

Laravel version 5.2 documentation website **[Filesystem / Cloud Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem)**.

Proposal contribution **[Filesystem / Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel-5.2/drafts/27980)**.

Comment: "copied content" is one of the reject reasons. That should suffice to answer your question.

Comment: Thx for your comment, is there any documentation section when I could find approve/reject reasons?

Comment: Just click reject; it'll give you a list. You can go back if none of them fit.

Comment: What if that content was posted to SO-docs by the original author, and originally published under a permissive licence (e.g. CC BY 4.0)? Are we going to reject content simply because it was used somewhere else, even if we have the appropriate permission to include it?

Comment: Hi @sanmiguel, feel free to update the original post including your questions.